# Stationary points and their nature. Calculus.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please explain how to do this question

$$y'(x)=x^2 (3-x) $$

Determine its two stationary points and their nature.

Now I've attempted the question, I got $(0,0)$ and $(3,0)$ but I can't find the nature of the point $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. The stationary point is defined as the point which $y'(x)=0$, hence they are 0 and 3, instead of $(0,0),(3,0)$.
2. As for nature of stationary point, consider a small pertubation $\epsilon$ around them $x^*$ and see it will eventually converge to or diverge from the point .

Answer (score 0):

Here $f'(x) = x^2(3-x)$

$\Rightarrow 
f''(x) = x^2(-1)+(3-x)(2x) = -x^2+6x-2x^2 = -3x^2+6x = -3x(x-2)$.

Now for since $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$, then there is a horizontal point of inflection provided there is a change in concavity.

And, $f'(3)=0$ , $f''(3)<0$ so there is a maximum turning point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Note that $y'(x)$ is positive (i.e. does not change sign) in a punctured neighbourhood $U'_\varepsilon(0)= \{x\colon\;\; 0<|x|<{\varepsilon}\}.$